# Build IntelliJ artifacts from command line

Tags: java, maven, gwt, ant, intellij-15

I recently started using IntelliJ to build my GWT project.
During my deployment process I have to build the necessary war file for the deploy, and the way I do that in my IntelliJ project is by going to build Artifacts, find the artifact there and go from there.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of a good tutorial to automate this process? I heard Ant might do what I need but I am unsure. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about maven? You already tagged your question with it ...

Answer (score 1):

[ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) to name a few could all be used.

Personally I find Gradle is the quickest to get up to speed with for beginners as there is less boilerplate code to write.